# Mapbox iOS SDK - MGLMapview crashes on setting zoomlevel

Tags: ios, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using two mapviews (MGLMapView) in my iOS app. For my use case, first mapview is shown to the user and then on a tab change second mapview is shown to the user.

I'm setting the max zoom level for both the mapviews to 23. When the tab changes I copy the zoom level of the first map to the secondmap by following

```
secondMap.zoolLevel = firstMap.zoomLevel
```

I have noticed that whenever the zoomLevel of the first map is more than 20 and I switch the tab, the app crashes with the following error:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Requested zoom higher than maxZoom: 21

I tried to print the max zoom level of the second map before setting the zoom, and it's 23 as I expect it to be. At no point of time does the zoom level of the first map go beyond 23 as it also has the maxzoom level set.

Does it have to do something with hiding and unhiding the mapviews? Like my second mapview is hidden in the beginning. Can someone from Mapbox confirm this?

Comment: Any help guys? I'm struggling with this.